# How can I print from a makefile each element on a row?

Tags: bash, makefile

I made a foreach where I am testing a condition and if it is not accomplished should print an error message for each variable on each row.

```
$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(if $(shell grep "aaa" "$(file)"),,@echo "" WARNING in: $(file)))
```

I made this code but it is printing all in one row (WARNING in: x    WARNING in: x ...) , and I want to print it like:

Warning in:

x

x ...

Comment: `foreach` is not a name in bash. I wonder how do you execute it. Do you also need to execute it in single line?

Comment: I don't really know how it works in backstage , this is the only method that I made to work near what I want , I execute it in a makefile : .PHONY : test      test: $....

Comment: I missed that you use it for `makefile`. Here some information is available https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html. You may also want to check foreach function in `c-shell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to remove your `@` and add an `;` behind.

```
$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(if $(shell grep "aaa" "$(file)"),,echo "" WARNING in: $(file);))
```

So that your command in the if-statement would be expanded to:

```
echo "" WARNING in: XXX; echo "" WARNING in: XXX;
  WARNING in: XXX
  WARNING in: XXX
```

Comment: It is there any way to remove the first printed line?

Comment: if the number of your `file` more than one, I don't think `@` can exist. It would be viewed as an invalid command.

Answer (score 1):

For

WARNING in: XXX

WARNING in: XXX

```
@$(foreach file,$(SOURCES),$(if $(shell grep "aaa" "$(file)"),,echo "" WARNING in: $(file);))
```

Because the @in front of a line is canceling the echoing of the makefile.